# How to resolve android soft keyboard when hidding textfield?

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, hide, textfield

I've some problem with my android application,
I've made a webview with some login field, but when 
I want to complete this field the soft keyboard appear and hide my text field, 
I've search some solution on google and tryed "WindowSoftInputMode" flag and other tips but nothing work.

To test my app, i'm using Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 and API Level 16.

Can you help me ?

Thank :)

Answer (score 0):

try this, Add windowSoftInputMode attribute in your manifest file for particular activity

```
 <activity android:name="YOurActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: thank for your help, but i've already tested that, but this problem still on my app